# JNA + running QT

Tags: java, c++, qt, jna

I need to run a QT application from Java using JNA. The problem is, that QT need to be run from the main thread, however I want to create it on a different thread and manage my java application instantaneously after creating qt window and just send some data to QT via JNA. When I create QTApp from a different thread I get warning "QAppplication was not created in the main() thread" and there is no response to GUI. Is there any clean solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a QCoreApplication in a QThread. Here is an example snippet from something I recently did:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
void run()
{
    int argc = 0;
    char* argv[1];// = new char[];
    QCoreApplication a(argc,&argv[0]);
    // More initilization code here
    a.exec();
}
};
```

Declare your thread in main and call `thread.start();`

Comment: But QCoreApplication is responsible for creating no GUI app right ? (according to documentation) and I want to create GUI window from a thread and just send some data to QT window using JNA.

Comment: QMainWindow requires a core application to run in background, so I presume this should work... also check this http://www.qtforum.org/article/24553/running-qapplication-within-a-qthread-run.html?s=7514b3d744a5ce211c4eb1655cdb5197cf5dc0c6#post87061

Comment: Well, in reality I use external library (Visualization Library) which uses QGLWidget to manage window. When I replace QApplication with QCoreApplication I get "qwidget cannot create a qwidget when no gui is being used"

Comment: I just tested my code by replacing QCoreApp with QApp... and it works fine so you definitely dont have to change that, if thats what is breaking your code

Comment: So I don't know where is the reason of this behaviour. I have very similar code to yours and get "QAppplication was not created in the main() thread"

Comment: hmm... It might b worth a try to switch the roles. i.e. GUI on main thread and your java app on the other

Comment: Maybe I didn't exactly explain the nature of my problem. I have big Java application which processes some data and my task is to visualize it using Visualization Library which uses Qt, so I've written JNA interface to comunicate between Java and Visualization library so the main thread works in Java app and I've encountered the problem I mentioned above.